# Adapter.Update(DataTable dt) не обновляет все записи

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Данные из таблицы базы данных отображаются в treeList1(DevExpress) и дублируются в dataGridView.
Пользователь изменяет данные в treeList1 (изменения происходят в DataTable dt и dataGridView1).

Для обновления данных в таблице базы данных используем выражение: adapter.Update(dt);

Вопрос.
Почему не обновляются все записи в таблице базы данных(см. Картинку)?

```
   //
using DevExpress.XtraTreeList;
using DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes;

namespace rsh
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt;        
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        OleDbCommandBuilder AccessCommandBuilder;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connect();

            // 
            treeList1.ForceInitialize();
            UpdateNodesPositions(treeList1.Nodes);
            treeList1.ExpandAll();
        }

        #region *** DB *** 

        public void connect()
        {
            string catBD = @"c:\test\visualStudio\csharp\01\01.accdb";
            string conBD = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", catBD);

            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conBD);

            connection.Open();

            string query1 = "SELECT * FROM TableTreeView_12";
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, connection);

            dt = new DataTable();

            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
            AccessCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.Fill(dt);


            treeList1.KeyFieldName = "ID";
            treeList1.ParentFieldName = "PrID";

            treeList1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            adapter.Update(dt);           

        }
        #endregion *** DB *** 

        private void treeList1_AfterDragNode(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.AfterDragNodeEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveNewRecordPosition(e);
        }

        private void SaveNewRecordPosition(NodeEventArgs e)
        {

            var nodes = e.Node.ParentNode == null
                        ? e.Node.TreeList.Nodes
                        : e.Node.ParentNode.Nodes;

            richTextBox1.Clear();
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
            {
                nodes[i].SetValue(0, i);


                string id = nodes[i].GetValue(0).ToString();
                string s = nodes[i].GetValue(1).ToString();

                richTextBox1.Text += id + " -//- " + s + "\r\n";

            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            Save();
        }

        private void UpdateNodesPositions(TreeListNodes nodes)
        {
            var ns = new List<TreeListNode>();
            foreach (TreeListNode n in nodes)
            {
                ns.Add(n);
            }
            foreach (TreeListNode n in ns)
            {
                UpdateNodesPositions(n.Nodes);
                n.TreeList.SetNodeIndex(n, Convert.ToInt32(n.GetValue("sorting")));

            }


        }
```

[image: Начальная позиция]
[image: Перетаскивание]
Скрин с ошибкой - см. комментарий (сюда ссылку не получилось вставить)

[image: Точка останова в adapter.Update(dt);]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление_1**
Изменил метод

```
   public void Save()
    {
                string s = adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText;
                adapter.Update(dt);           

    }
```

Получаю ошибку:   System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." - System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.get вернул null.

**Обновление_2**
Изменил метод  `Save()`

```
public void Save()
        {
            //adapter.Update(dt);
            adapter.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
            string s = adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText;
        }
```

В `string s` получаю:

```
UPDATE TableTreeView_12   
SET PrID = ?, sorting = ?, NodeName = ?   
WHERE ((ID = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND PrID IS NULL) OR (PrID = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND sorting IS NULL) OR (sorting = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND NodeName IS NULL) OR (NodeName = ?)))
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85445/discussion-on-question-by-eusataf-adapter-updatedatatable-dt---).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ходе обсуждения в комментариях/чате, ответ был найден.

При создании адаптера его свойства `UpdateCommand`, `InsertCommand`, `DeleteCommand` равны `null`.

Нужно задать их либо вручную:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE ...");
```

либо сгенерировать автоматически при помощи `OleDbCommandBuilder`. Это делается вызовом метода `GetUpdateCommand`:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
```

Более того, достаточно просто вызвать

```
cb.GetUpdateCommand();
```

Команда будет присвоена тому адаптеру, который был передан в конструктор билдера.

---

Важно! В документации базового класса [DbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.getupdatecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) сказано:

> The SQL statements are first generated either when the application calls Update or GetUpdateCommand.

То есть необязательно вызывать `GetUpdateCommand` - он будет вызван автоматически при первом вызове `Update`.

Однако, в классе потомке [OleDbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.getupdatecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) текст немного изменен:

> The SQL statements are first generated when the application calls either UpdateCommand or GetUpdateCommand.

Судя по всему, вызова `Update` недостаточно.

---

Полезная ссылка: [Обновление источников данных с объектами DataAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters).